# Magento 2: Select Field From Collection Query

Tags: magento2, collection, magento2.1.5

I have below query. I want to select only 1 field from table instead of all.

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->addFieldToFilter('status', 0)->load();
//$collection->getSelect()->column('id');
//$collection->getSelect()->from(['main_table' => $this->getMainTable()], array('main_table.id'));
echo $collectionBallotSelect->getSelect()->__toString();
exit;
```

I want to select only `id` field from table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also Try :

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('id')->addFieldToFilter('status', 0)->load();
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to reset all column first, then select specific column. Try following way:

```
$collection->getSelect()
            ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
            ->columns(['id']);
```

Comment: This one worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use this query.

```
        $getTotalRecommended = $getCollection ->getSelect()
        ->reset(\Zend_Db_Select::COLUMNS)
        ->columns(['detail.recommended']);
```

where **detail** is the alias of the table name and **recommended** is the name of col